# Properly handling separate credentials per branch in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My current setup involves having 2 freestyle projects in Jenkins, both doing exactly the same flow with different parameters. I wanted to rework it and it seemed like using Pipeline instead of that mess was a better idea in general. I also need a couple of credential bindings:

- database password (string)
- Docker Host Credentials
- HTTP username/password for basic auth (username and password pair)
- some secret keys etc. I don't want to hardcode these anywhere

I also need some more parameters. My issue is, I want all of these to be different PER BRANCH, for example:

- master: use credentials for prod, production DB password, no HTTP username and password, production secret keys
- stage: use credentials for stage, stage DB password, HTTP username and password, stage secret keys
- anything else: don't deploy anything

I wanted to solve this by saving credential IDs as parameters, like this:

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'DB_CREDENTIALS_ID', defaultValue: '', description: 'DB password')
    string(name: 'HTTP_CREDENTIALS_ID', defaultValue: '', description: 'DB password')
    string(name: 'DOCKER_CREDENTIALS_ID', defaultValue: 'docker_cert', description: 'Credentials ID')
    ...
}
```

But I have no clue where/how can I override these default values. I want these to be managed on Jenkins side. Maybe my approach is completely wrong? What is considered a good practice when using credential bindings in Jenkins pipeline? I really hope it's not hard-coding credential IDs in Jenkinsfile.

Comment: "I really hope it's not hard-coding credential IDs in Jenkinsfile." Why? What's wrong with that? It would not leak any sensitive information.

Comment: I'd rather be able to do these bindings at Jenkins level, so I wouldn't have to worry about credential ID being incorrect in Jenkinsfile if something changes.

Comment: Well you have to write down the credential IDs *somewhere*.  If not in the Jenkinsfile, where would you put them?